# How to convert RGB percentage to RGB values?

Tags: python, colors, rgb

Given the RGB percentages of a color, e.g. "[wild watermelon](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Carmine_(color)#Wild_watermelon)", `(99%, 42%, 52%)`, the right RGB values are `(252, 108, 133)`.

But when I tried

```py
rgb_percent = ('99%', '42%','52%')
rgb_values = tuple(int(int(s.strip('%')) * 2.55) for s in rgb_percent)
print(rgb_values)
```

[out]:

```
(252, 107, 132)
```

The color looks similar but they are not the right values. **How to convert RGB percentage to RGB values correctly?**

**Should I be rounding up/down them instead or casting the values to integer?** This seems closer but not the expected values still:

```
tuple(int(round(int(s.strip('%')) * 2.55, 0)) for s in rgb_percent)
```

[out]:

```
(252, 107, 133)
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You cannot get exactly the same values, because you round numbers. 100 and 255 are not multiples. Your percentage RGB seems to be all integer, so you lost at minimum 1 bit of information (and possibly also 2 bits). So you cannot expect exact values on all cases. (You cannot map 100 numbers into 256 values, and get all 256 values).

But the good: you do not need it (usually). Your eyes are not so sensible (and we cannot see all combination of RGB with 256x256x256 values: our eyes can distinguish a lot less colours, so on some case you will see no differences, and on some, it is just barely noticeable). In addition some monitor panel trick displaying only 64 different shades per channel (and few people notice it). Consider that if you took data from a JPEG image, you get an additional conversion (data are not stored as RGB data, but as YCC).

To get the best choice, you need to know the original algorithm (do they `round` or `trunc`? or you should have a larger example test, and check the differences between different algorithms (e.g. how many cases are precise, how many are just 1 off, 2 off, 3 off).

Note: you have 3 possibilities: `round()`, `math.floor()`, and `math.ceil()`. I would avoid using `int`: according Python documentation, it seems the result depend on the system standard library (it could be truncated, or rounded). Note: `math.trunc()` and `math.floor()` gives the same results for positive (or zero) numbers.

In general, I would prefer round: it gives expected results for 0% and 100% (ceil is similar for these extreme values).

PS: there is not "correct RGB values". Historically RGB were given as numbers from 0 to 100 (and possibly as floating point number), or from 0.0 to 1.0. Just HTML pushed for 0 to 255, but it causes problems if you have a screens which can display more colours. And probably for RGB you mean R*G*B*, so not a linear RGB, but a OETF corrected RGB).

And no: there is not reputable sources. Nobody follows standards, so do not expect people which converted the colour channel (e.g. to `99%`) are using exact the same method (we programmers are lazy). And standards tend to uses floating points. Note: internally a program may use floating point numbers, so in a colour picker you may get different colours with same *displayed* %-values, depending on how you input the colour. Or do you refer to a specific standard which specifies *%-values*? We cannot agree if black is 0,0,0 or 16,16,16 (e.g. MPEG-2, or TVs, and other *limited range RGB* devices), or how do do or interpret the gamma correction (ok: recent and less-recent standards are more precise, but most programs didn't get it). Also when reading your "RGB" values, in past I would assume it would be sRGB (so colour space of web and Microsoft), but since few years Apple use a different colour space (Apple P3), and other are following *extending* sRGB. Chaos. So just test different methods (and use your eyes to check quality).

Answer (score 1):

Instead of rediscovering the nature of different color codes I researched the packages and find one usable and detailed package for this. When we look at the code of this package similar problems have been mentioned and solved. With this package with the help of bit reverse engineering I found this way:

```
#pip install webcolors #to install
import webcolors as wco
hex = wco.rgb_percent_to_hex(('99%','42%','52%'))
wco.hex_to_rgb(hex)
```

Resut is `IntegerRGB(red=252, green=107, blue=133)`.

Although there is no `rgb_percent_to_rgb`  function instead of this I converted percentage values to HEX and then converted them to values.

Comment: This package is great.  Thanks for pointing it out.  Your answer gets my upvote.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, round up before casting them to int values but remember float values aren't precise so you won't always get the expected output

Comment: Remember that when you are working with percents your numbers will be in the range of 0 to 100; trying to convert to a hexadecimal integer equivalent isn't always going to be possible.